# query inside query where sum of table2.amount (if stat=1) is greate than sum of table 1 expense

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

table:**transaction**

```
id . user_id . amount . status
1 - - 100 -- --- 500 - ----- 1
2 - - 100 -- --- 100 - ----- 0
3 - - 110 -- --- 200 - ----- 1
```

table:**campaign**

```
id . user_id . bid . status . budget . expense . size
1 -- 100 ---- 80  --- 1 ------- 200 ------ 200 ---- 5 --
2 -- 109 ---- 75  --- 1 ------- 050 ------ 030 ---- 2 --
3 -- 100 ---- 65  --- 1 ------- 700 ------ 065 ---- 2 --
4 -- 107 ---- 77  --- 0 ------- 020 ------ 020 ---- 2 --
5 -- 90 ----- 87  --- 1 ------- 120 ------ 090 ---- 7 --
```

I need campaign.id after filters using php and mysql

condition: if total money/transaction received from a user is greater than total expenses by a user. Money is also approved money (1=approved, 0=pending). Campaign is on means 1, who placed maximum bid

```
(sum(transaction.amount) WHERE transaction.status = 1 of that any user) > sum(campaign.expense of that user)
```

bid = max(bid)

Camps status = 1

**1 step solution**

```
 mysql_query("SELECT campaign.* FROM campaign c,transaction t  
            WHERE budget>expense AND status='1' AND size='2' 
            ON c.user_id=t.user_id 
            HAVING SUM (CASE WHEN transaction.status=1 THEN transaction.amount ELSE 0 END) > SUM(campaign.expense)"));
```

*not working*

Alternatively if any solution in 3 steps -

**1st step**

```
   mysql_query("SELECT id,user_id FROM campaign 
        WHERE budget>expense AND status='1' AND size='2'")
```

**2nd step**

```
  keep id,user_id of 1st step WHERE SUM(transaction.amount status=1)
             > SUM(campaign.expense)
```

**3rd step**

```
  mysql_query("SELECT id,user_id FROM campaign 
        WHERE step2 satisfied")
```

Please help, I will sleep after solving it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT camps.id,camps.bid FROM camps c JOIN tran t  ON c.user_id=t.user_id 
    HAVING SUM (CASE WHEN tran.status=1 THEN tran.amount ELSE 0 END)
       > SUM(CASE WHEN camp.status= 1 THEN camps.expense ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: I added more explanation with original problem, please look, I spent so many hours and tired. please help

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to achieve the following:

```
SELECT 
    c.*
FROM campaign c
JOIN (SELECT
        SUM(amount) AS summed
    FROM transaction t
    WHERE status = 1
) temp t
WHERE c.status = 1
HAVING t.summed > SUM(c.expense)
ORDER BY c.bid DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: user_id.camps should match user_id.tran to make sure that those user have balance get chance

Comment: one thing missing, result will be campaign.id where user_id has balance. Balance = total of approved transaction.amount of that user - total of all campaign.expense of that user(no matter campaign status = 0 or 1). additional condition campaign.status =1, budget>expense of that campaign, and size = 2