# Data from another table with multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables

table:**transaction**

```
id . user_id . amount . status
1 - - 100 -- --- 500 - ----- 1
2 - - 100 -- --- 100 - ----- 0
3 - - 110 -- --- 200 - ----- 1
4 - - 100 -- --- 220 - ----- 1
5 - - 117 -- --- 120 - ----- 1
6 - - 122 -- --- 300 - ----- 1
```

this means deposit by users but only **status=1** are valid

table:**campaign**

```
id . user_id . bid . status . budget . expense . size. priority
1 -- 100 ---- 80  --- 0 ------- 200 ------ 200 --- 5 -- 1
2 -- 109 ---- 75  --- 1 ------- 050 ------ 030 --- 2 -- 2
3 -- 100 ---- 65  --- 1 ------- 700 ------ 065 --- 2 -- 4
4 -- 107 ---- 77  --- 0 ------- 020 ------ 020 --- 2 -- 3
5 -- 90 ----- 87  --- 1 ------- 120 ------ 090 --- 7 -- 7
```

I need the id of campaign after filtering by below (using php and mysql)

Conditions:

```
01. campaign.status = 1
02. campaign.size = 2
03. campaign.budget > campaign.expense

04. those user_id has balance (balance = A - B)
      A = sum(transaction.amount where transaction.status=1)
      B = sum(campaign.expense)
05. order by bid max value
```

expected output campaign.id = 3

```
for campaign.id 3 :  status 1, size 2, budget 700 > expense 65
balance > 0 means for user_id 100 = A(500+220) > B(200+65) //means A-B = 455
```

I am not that much expert. tried several ways

Please help, I will sleep after solving it. Lost 2 days.

Comment: *What* is not working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: What is `funded`? I don't understand your conditions

Comment: As far as I understand you, this should work: SELECT
 campaign.id
FROM
 campaign
JOIN
 transaction ON transaction.user_id = campaign.user_id
WHERE
 campaign.status = 1 AND
 campaign.size = 2 AND
 campaign.budget > campaign.expense AND
 SUM(transaction.amount) > SUM(campaign.expense)
ORDER BY
 campaign.bid DESC

Comment: condition 4 explained, please look and write whatever you think ok

Comment: `has balance (balance = A - B)` = `A - B > 0` = `A > B` = `sum(transaction.amount) > sum(campaign.expense)` => `SELECT
 campaign.id
FROM
 campaign
JOIN
 transaction ON transaction.user_id = campaign.user_id
WHERE
 campaign.status = 1 AND
 campaign.size = 2 AND
 campaign.budget > campaign.expense AND
 transaction.status = 1 AND
 SUM(transaction.amount) > SUM(campaign.expense)
ORDER BY
 campaign.bid DESC`

Comment: possible duplicate of [query inside query where sum of table2.amount (if stat=1) is greate than sum of table 1 expense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604984/query-inside-query-where-sum-of-table2-amount-if-stat-1-is-greate-than-sum-of)

Comment: please write me "SELECT ..." full code @MostyMostacho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM campaign c
WHERE 
  c.status = 1
  AND c.size = 2
  AND c.budget > c.expense
  AND
    ( SELECT sum( amount )
      FROM transaction t
      WHERE t.user_id = c.user_id
    )
   -
    ( SELECT sum( expense )
      FROM campaign c1
      WHERE c.user_id = c1.user_id AND t.status=1
    )
    > 0
;
```

and another:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (
   SELECT user_id, sum( amount ) amount
   FROM transaction t
   WHERE EXISTS(
      SELECT 1 FROM campaign c
      WHERE t.user_id = c.user_id
        AND c.status = 1 
        AND c.size = 2
        AND c.budget > c.expense
     )
   GROUP BY user_id
) q1
JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, sum( expense ) expense
   FROM campaign c
   WHERE EXISTS(
      SELECT 1 FROM campaign c1
      WHERE c.user_id = c1.user_id
        AND c1.status = 1 
        AND c1.size = 2
        AND c1.budget > c.expense
     )
   GROUP BY user_id
) q2
ON q1.user_id = q2.user_id AND q1.amount - q2.expense > 0
JOIN campaign c
ON c.user_id = q1.user_id
WHERE c.status = 1 
  AND c.size = 2
  AND c.budget > c.expense
```

Demo (of both queries): http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/414ca5/2

Please try both of them on your data, I am not sure which one will perform better (probably the first one).
Both queries need at least indexes on `user_id` columns for both tables to gain better performance:

```
CREATE INDEX camp_user_id ON campaign( user_id );
CREATE INDEX trans_user_id ON transaction( user_id );
```

Comment: 1st one worked with an edit. please look, I edited your answer